# Create dll file in runtime doesn't work in c#

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I am trying to create a DLL file in runtime ,as a matter of fact i need to save an encoded data to `DLL` .My code is like this :

```
 class DllFile
    {
        public static void CreateDllFile(string source)
        {
            var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var options = new CompilerParameters
            {
                OutputAssembly = "test.dll"
            };

        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });
        }
    }
```

I expect from this code to create a dll file but it doesn't create

```
The error is :The pointer for this method was null
```

Best regards.Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Check the result of `CompileAssemblyFromSource`.

Comment: It could very well have been built in memory. Check the result, sample code at bottom of MSDN article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @500-InternalServerError how can i do that dear friend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation errors are reported via the returned value:

```
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });
```

Now check `results`, and in particular `results.Errors`.

You can also check `results.NativeCompilerReturnValue` - that should be `0` for success, and non-zero for failure.

Comment: thank you dear friend the error is :Message = "The pointer for this method was null."

Comment: When i expand the result error i see this error :A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Comment: @EA then: the C# you have sent to it **is not valid**. Fix the data in `source`.

Comment: I save this string in my file :            var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() });
 ,but same error is happened

Comment: @EA huh? cannot parse your comment

Comment: You said my c# code is not valid in fact i need to store a hashed code in my dll file ,i just need this could you please give me some help how can i save this in test.dll ?

Comment: @EA what is the value of `source` here? It is meant to be fully valid C# code. You are passing it to a C# compiler, after all - not just a random dll creator.

Comment: The value is a encoded data like this :DF33433223232JJFGJFHGJFGF

Comment: @EA that is not C#. You are invoking a C# compiler with (essentially) garbage. That is **not going to work**. For exactly the same reason that it doesn't work if you drop `DF33433223232JJFGJFHGJFGF` into a `.cs` file in Visual Studio and hit "build".

Comment: I got my errors ,thank you .   source = @"
    using System;

    namespace First
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
            " +
                "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");"
                + @"
            }
        }
    }
";

Answer (score 1):

Any errors would be in the Errors property of the [CompilerResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults(v=vs.110).aspx) returned from the CompileAssemblyFromSource method. Have you tried printing them out to see if there are errors ?

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });

foreach(CompilerError error in results.Errors)
{
      Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
}
```

Comment: dear friend my error is :The error is :The pointer for this method was null

Comment: You would need to give the compiler proper C# code, complete with a namespace, class declaration and methods. You cannot compile snippets of code.

Comment: You know  this code is worked before ,i just need to store a encoded data in the dll file

Comment: You know i need to store a license code in dll and read that again